# Format for distance matrix for running hclust in R

Tags: r, clustering

I am using R for a simple hierarchical clustering method for finding protein sequence similarities. I already have a distance matrix computed. I am using the `hclust` method to run it (thus I dont want to use `dist` method). Could anyone tell me what format does my distance matrix need to be for `hclust` to run?

I used the `read.xls` method to read my Excel file. I need only the lower triangular portion of the matrix, and this is what I am sending to `hclust` to be clustered.

```
d= as.matrix(mat)
hc =hclust(d, method="single")
```

However this is the error I get:

```
Error in if (n < 2) stop("must have n >= 2 objects to cluster") : 
argument is of length zero
```

Comment: Can't you just replace `as.matrix` by `as.dist`?

Comment: @chl I tried as.dist function. But I got the error like this.Error in hclust(as.dist(mat), method = "single") : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)

Comment: I suspect you have some missing value(s) in your distance matrix (which doesn't hurt `as.dist` but `hclust`). You may want to impute them or try [hybridHclust](http://math.acadiau.ca/chipmanh/hybridHclust/) (never used myself).

Comment: Any progress on your problem?